# How to find to 30 biggest numbers from 1000 in dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Here is my dictionary:

```
d['any1'] = 15
d['any2'] = 27
d['any3'] = 84
d['any4'] = 12
d['any5'] = 7
....
d['any1243'] = 24
```

Is there any python tool that will help me find 30 biggest numbers from 1243 in dictionary?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `d` is a dictionary object and the op is accessing its keys?

Comment: @NWard: There was no `d` in the first revision. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be better off using a [`collections.Counter()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter); `Counter`s support this usecase explicitly with the [`Counter.most_common()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

> Return a list of the *n* most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least.

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(d)
for key, freq in counts.most_common(30):
    print key, freq
```

where you'd actually use the `Counter()` object *instead* of `d` to begin with. `Counter` objects are a `dict` subclass, so you can use them as drop-in replacements when you are keeping track of per-key frequencies, albeit that they make counting items a lot easier in many cases.

If you are stuck with a regular dictionary, then you can implement this functionality yourself using the [`heapq` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html), specifically, the [`heapq.nlargest()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter

thirty_largest = heapq.nlargest(30, d.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

where `thirty_largest` is then a list of 30 key-value tuples:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> import random
>>> d = {'any{}'.format(i): random.randrange(5000) for i in range(1243)}
>>> for key, value in heapq.nlargest(30, d.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1)):
...     print '{:<7} {:>4}'.format(key, value)
... 
any1226 4997
any1150 4997
any1225 4993
any401  4992
any949  4988
any130  4978
any1069 4977
any96   4974
any955  4974
any229  4970
any1117 4966
any883  4964
any937  4961
any729  4958
any981  4958
any7    4952
any1045 4952
any600  4950
any134  4948
any16   4937
any312  4937
any1158 4937
any1238 4932
any315  4932
any875  4930
any339  4930
any295  4926
any878  4925
any343  4922
any681  4917
```

Answer (score 1):

For that many values, you can do it in a couple of lines like:

```
import operator
d = ...
s = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print s[:30]
```

Comment: For just the top 30 a full sort is overkill. The `heapq` approach is *far* faster for larger number of items.

Comment: Note that the [`Counter.most_common()` source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/740bd510a888/Lib/collections.py#l457) uses `sorted()` *only* if there is no limit to the number of items listed. For `.most_common(30)`, `heapq` is used exactly as my answer shows.

Comment: Indeed, I just wanted to point out the more "naive" approach that works fine if the number of items is what the OP stated.